# Make this code run on first character

Tags: batch-file, command

I was given some batch code that takes a variable and converts it to uppercase characters. ie, joshua will become JOSHUA. I've been reading the documentation for the commands used and I cannot work out quite how the code works, but I would like to amend the code so it only capitalizes the first character. ie, joshua to Joshua. I assume it is just a matter of modifying the 'loop' (?) that the code uses. Any help or advice appreciated.

Code -

```
 :toUpper str -- converts lowercase character to uppercase
 if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
 for %%a in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I"
        "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R"
        "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z" "ä=Ä"
        "ö=Ö" "ü=Ü") do (
call set %~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%
)
EXIT /b
```

Note: I could not find any reference to the meaning of the multiple % signs in the SET help documentation. I am guessing this is where the key to the problem lies.

Cheers

EDIT: If someone could give a very brief explanation of what is going on in the code that would be fantastic also! The only part I understand is it is substituting the lower case letters for an uppercase letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalizing first letter will require different approach:

```
@echo off


set "name=npocmaka"
echo before firstToUpper - %name%

call ::firstToUpper name

echo after firstToUpper - %name%
exit /b 0


:firstToUpper var
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "name=!%~1!"

set first_letter=%name:~0,1%
set last_letters=%name:~1%

for %%# in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    set first_letter=!first_letter:%%#=%%#!
)

set "name=%first_letter%%last_letters%"

endlocal && (
    set "%~1=%name%"
)
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

To understand this you might need to look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) , [string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). Notice that when replacing search of the letter is not case sensitive but [replacement itself is](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php)

Comment: Thank you. Any advice on calling this in my current code. I currently use the other code with the following --------

call :toUpper ExampleVariable    --------

Is this possible with the code you provided?

Comment: @JoshuaPatterson so you want to assign the result to ExampleVariable  and initially the name is contained in variable ExampleVariable ?

Comment: Sorted it, thank you. A typo in my own code was causing this code to fail!

Comment: Cheers for that, problem all sorted :-)